# how to use mysql variables when creating database

Tags: mysql

```
set @username = "botany";
set @password = "botany";
set @databaseName = "botanyDatabase";
drop database if exists @databaseName;
```

this is the code. But it gives the error message:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 4 in file: '/home/list/botany/app/botany.sql': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@databaseName' at line 1
```

So how can i use the variables when creating database.

Comment: you can't  use variable as object name  .. in sql

Comment: Simple answer is you can't.

Comment: ok. Thanks any way.